# RegEx to capture values in a string into a group, regardless of order?

Tags: regex, pcre

I have a bunch of strings in a text file that have values in them I want to capture into groups.  Each line/row in the text file is a unique record, but the values usually stick to a prescribed format in each line:

```
ValueA ValueD ValueS ValueR ValueW ValueT
ValueX ValueW ValueB ValueM ValueQ ValueA
```

Etc.  If I want to capture `ValueA` into capture group 1 and `ValueW` into capture group 2, can I do so using a single regex that handles things properly irrespective of the position in each line of text of the values in question?

The goal is to then use the capture groups to write back out to a file the two captured values so that I can order them, i.e., "ValueW ValueA".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
^(?=.*?(ValueA))(?=.*?(ValueW)).*
```

Perl example:

```
$_ = <<'_STR_';
ValueA ValueD ValueS ValueR ValueW ValueT
ValueX ValueW ValueB ValueM ValueQ ValueA
_STR_

s/^(?=.*?(ValueA))(?=.*?(ValueW)).*/$1 $2/gm;

print;
```

Output:

```
ValueA ValueW
ValueA ValueW
```

Also at http://ideone.com/IhGfS

Note: If you are just matching you won't need that last `.*`, and depending on how well matching the ValueX patterns are you could remove all the `?`.

Comment: Take off the leading caret, and this works perfectly!  Thanks!

Comment: `^` should be used, make sure you are using the multiline mode `/m` if operating on one string.

Comment: Correct, though it seems to work either way.  Gets confused on quoted strings, I think a greedy match instead of a lazy match, but a second regex run fixes that really easily.

Comment: Does this need to be written differently to work in sed?  I've tried several variations, and sed just spits back out the original text, unmodified.  All the manual pages say sed fully implements PCRE, but it doesn't seem to support named capture groups at all.  Mind you, I am using a version of sed packaged with 'git' for Windows, which I think is linked against mingw (not cygwin).  They may be doing something differently with that.

Comment: I don't know about sed, but if you got Perl you could do things like `perl -pe "s/^(?=.*?(ValueA))(?=.*?(ValueW)).*/$1 $2/gm" file.txt`

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot later on.  Gave up on sed and egrep after some more fiddling around.  Was mostly just an experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
(?<ValueA>ValueA)|(?<ValueW>ValueW)
```

Comment: I've tried this.  The OR statement only captures one or the other.  Both are present in each line, but their order is different.  I'm open to trying this with two separate regex recipes (I can write a bash script if needed), but was seeing if it could be done in just one, maybe via egrep or sed.

Answer (score 0):

assuming its unix, first find and replace space with newline, pipe it with the various regex's,then output the groups to a file.

Answer (score 0):

This is regex abuse -  call the cops!

Seriously... if you HAVE to do this, you could use the or operator (|) in each group to select one or the other of the two words.

Comment: BTW - this depends a lot on which regex.  Always tag regex posts with the kind you mean.

Comment: Sorry, it's PCRE regex.  I'll adjust the tags.  Thanks!